# Investigate disk writes further to find out which process writes to my SSD

Tags: ssd, disk-usage, optimization

I try to minimize disk writes to my new SSD system drive.
I'm stuck with iostat output:

```
~ > iostat -d 10 /dev/sdb
Linux 2.6.32-44-generic (Pluto)     13.11.2012  _i686_  (2 CPU)

Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sdb               8,60       212,67       119,45   21010156   11800488

Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sdb               3,00         0,00        40,00          0        400

Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sdb               1,70         0,00        18,40          0        184

Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sdb               1,20         0,00        28,80          0        288

Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sdb               2,20         0,00        32,80          0        328

Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sdb               1,20         0,00        23,20          0        232

Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sdb               3,40        19,20        42,40        192        424
```

As I see there are writes to sdb. How can I resolve **which process** writes?

I know about **iotop**, but it doesn't show which filesystem is being accessed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following uses the kernel's virtual memory block dump mechanism. First get the perl script:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/true/aspersa-mirror/master/iodump
```

Then turn on block dump:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/block_dump
```

And run the following:

```
while true; do sleep 1; sudo dmesg -c; done  | perl iodump
```

..and press <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> to finish, you will see something like the following:

```
^C# Caught SIGINT.
TASK                   PID      TOTAL       READ      WRITE      DIRTY DEVICES
jbd2/sda3-8            620         40          0         40          0 sda3
jbd2/sda1-8            323         21          0         21          0 sda1
#1                    4746         11          0         11          0 sda3
flush-8:0             2759          7          0          7          0 sda1, sda3
command-not-fou       9703          4          4          0          0 sda1
mpegaudioparse8       8167          2          2          0          0 sda3
bash                  9704          1          1          0          0 sda1
bash                  9489          1          0          1          0 sda3
mount.ecryptfs_       9698          1          1          0          0 sda1
```

And turn off block dump when you are finished:

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/block_dump
```

Thanks to http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2009/08/23/how-to-find-per-process-io-statistics-on-linux/ for this helpful info.

Answer (score 11):

You could at least start with `iotop`. It won't tell you which filesystem is being written but it will give you some processes to investigate.

```
sudo apt-get install iotop
sudo iotop
```

It shows instantaneous disk reads and writes and the name of the command reading or writing.

If you are trying to catch a process that writes infrequently, you can use the `--accumulated` option or log the output to a file:

```
sudo -i
iotop --batch > iotop_log_file
```

Obviously the writing of the log file will show up in the results, but you should also be able to `grep` for other processes writing to disk.

By this point you should be able to find some candidate suspect processes. The left column in `iotop` shows the *pid*. Next, find out which file descriptor the process is writing to:

```
sudo -i
strace -p <pid> 2>&1 | grep write
```

You should see output like this when the process writes:

```
write(1, "\n", 1)                       = 1
write(4, "test\n", 5)                   = 5
write(1, ">>> ", 4)                     = 4
```

The first argument to write is the file descriptor. We are probably looking for values greater than 2, because 0, 1 and 2 are just stdin, stdout and stderr. File descriptor 4 looks interesting.

You can now find out what file the file descriptor points to with:

```
lsof -p <pid>
```

Which should yield output like:

```
...
python  23908  rob  mem    REG    8,1    26258 8392656 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
python  23908  rob    0u   CHR  136,5      0t0       8 /dev/pts/5
python  23908  rob    1u   CHR  136,5      0t0       8 /dev/pts/5
python  23908  rob    2u   CHR  136,5      0t0       8 /dev/pts/5
python  23908  rob    3w   REG   0,25      909 9049082 /home/rob/testfile
python  23908  rob    4w   REG   0,25       20 9049087 /home/rob/another_test_file
```

Look at the 4th column. `4w` means that file descriptor 4 is open for writing and the file is `another_test_file`.

It is possible for a process to open, write and then close a file, in which case `lsof` would not show it. You might catch this happening with:

```
strace -p <pid> 2>&1 | grep open
```

Comment: I didn't know about **--accumulte** That is really cool feature! Thank you very much for that!!!

iotop --batch output redirecting fails with UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 92-99: ordinal not in range(128) in File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/iotop/ui.py", line 405, in refresh_display

Comment: I'm glad my answer was of some use at least. The redirection works for me; not sure I can explain that.

Comment: Ok, I played around a bit and found I could use lsof and strace to at least do enough detective work to catch processes writing to an SSD. Hopefully this finally answers the question as asked, though it looks like Colin Ian King's answer is easier!

Comment: Sorry for late response, I had nothing to say until I played with strace. Thank you for that another clever approach, I voted up. I found it quite difficult to write script to implement it, due to little experience in writing shell scripts. That is why I've choosen another solution. Thank you for sharing your knowledge!

Comment: Should be `--accumulated`, but stack exchange requires 6 characters to accept edit of the post.